# Creating an email which populates an image based on Data Extension upload

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio, automation, email-studio

I'm trying to send a survey to recipients with an image in the email. Ideally I could upload a list to Data extensions that would populate an image and some text. Each row would have an ID that would call a particular image from my media library.

Anyone try this before?

Comment: would you store the image name or the image’s external key in the image lookup DE? Is there a relationship between your send DE and your image look up DE?

Comment: Image would be identified by name in media library and would correspond with a name in the send DE. Just not sure how to structure it

Answer (score 1):

If you had a DE named IMAGELOOKUPDE that has 2 fields i.e ImageName and ImageExtKey and the Sendable DE you using for your send has a field named ImageNameFromSendDE which matches the ImageName from ImageLookupDE then you can have the below code that will return the full img tag for your image

```
    %%[
    SET @getimageExtKey = Lookup('IMAGELOOKUPDE','ImageExtKey','ImageName',ImageNameFromSendDE)
    ]%%

    %%=ContentImagebyKey(@getimageExtKey)=%%
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below approach to get the solution:

- You need to upload all the images to be used in the email on the platform first. Collect the URL for the images that you upload.
- Create a DE say image_refer and have fields image_id and image_url. Add the URL's in the DE with their dummy id's. Example: 001(image_id)      **The URL**
- Create DE where you have subscriber data. Insert a column that could refer as foreign key.
- In email, write lookup function to get the image url (suppose you get it in @URL) and in HTML code,
  <a href= %%==v(@URL)==%% ................ >

Your image will be populated based on your selected subscriber.